# How to implement the timer to run inside Alarm Receiver even after the app quits?

Tags: android, handler, timertask, quit, localbroadcastmanager

I have used Alarm Service. I have implemented the the alarm to run on every 1 minute. So the broadcast receiver onReceive method gets called even after the app quits. I want to implement a timer inside of this onReceive method. I have to start location tracking and wait for 20 Seconds after that I need to stop the location tracking.

I have tried the below,

```
TimerTask
Handler
Local Broadcast Receiver
```

But all the above not capable of running once the app quits.

Inside the alarm receiver I want to implement timer to wait for 20 seconds.
How can I achieve this when the app is in quit state?

**My AlaramReceiver onReceive Method:**

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mSharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mContext);

    mAppUtilInstance.logDebugMessage(TAG, "Track interval alarm receiver.");

    // // Check the preference having any current activity
    if (mSharedPrefManager.checkForCurrentActivityPref()) {
        userActivity = mSharedPrefManager.getCurrentUserActivityPref();

        if (mSharedPrefManager.getIsUserMovedPref()) {
            // User MOVED
            // Call the location service
            LocationUpdateTimer locationUpdateTimer = new LocationUpdateTimer(
            mContext, userActivity, true);
                locationUpdateTimer.initialize();
            mSharedPrefManager.setIsUserMovedPref(false);
        } else {
            // User not MOVED in between the track interval period. He is
            // IDLE
            // Check whether the location information is returned by the
            // google API
            if (mSharedPrefManager.checkForLocationEntityPref()
                    && mSharedPrefManager.getLocationEntityPref()
                            .getLatitude().length() > 0) {
                // Send the packet information to the Fleetilla server
                StoreAndSendLocationInformation storeAndSendLocationInformation = new StoreAndSendLocationInformation(
                        mContext,
                        mSharedPrefManager.getLocationEntityPref(),
                        userActivity);
                storeAndSendLocationInformation.storeAndSend();
            } else {
                // If the location information is not available
                mAppUtilInstance
                        .logDebugMessage(TAG,
                                "Location information is not generated to store and send.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Location Update Timer Class:**

```
/**
 * LocationUpdateTimer Constructor
 */
public LocationUpdateTimer(Context context, String userActivity,
        boolean isTosend) {
    // Save the context
    mContext = context;
    mUserCurrentActivity = userActivity;
    isToSendLocationInfo = isTosend;
}

/**
 * To start the location reporting
 */
private void startLocationReporting() {
    if (mLocationProviderStatusListener != null) {
        mLocationProviderStatusListener
                .requestLocationProvidersToUpdateStatus(mConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
        scheduleTimerTask();
    }
}

/**
 * To schedule the 20 seconds timer task to get the best location
 * information and send it to Fleetilla server.
 */
private void scheduleTimerTask() {
    bestGPSInfoTimerHandler = new Handler();
    bestGPSInfoTimerHandler.postDelayed(bestGPSInfoRunnable,
            Constants.TIMER_TASK_DELAY);
    mAppUtilInstance.logDebugMessage(TAG,
            "20 Sec Location Update TimerTask Scheduled");
}

/**
 * To cancel the timer tack which was scheduled for 30sec location update
 */
private void cancelTimerTask() {
    if (bestGPSInfoTimerHandler != null) {
        mAppUtilInstance.logDebugMessage(TAG, "20 sec TimerTask canceled");
        bestGPSInfoTimerHandler.removeCallbacks(bestGPSInfoRunnable);
        bestGPSInfoTimerHandler = null;
    }
}
/**
 * A runnable will be called after the 20 sec time interval
 */
Runnable bestGPSInfoRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Called after 20 seconds
        mAppUtilInstance.logDebugMessage(TAG,
                "TimerTask running after 20 sec interval.");
        stopLocationReporting();
        cancelTimerTask();

        if (isToSendLocationInfo) {
            // Check whether the location information is returned by the
            // google api
            if (mSharedPrefManager.checkForLocationEntityPref()
                    && mSharedPrefManager.getLocationEntityPref()
                            .getLatitude().length() > 0) {
                // Send the packet information to the server
                StoreAndSendLocationInformation storeAndSendLocationInformation = new StoreAndSendLocationInformation(
                        mContext,
                        mSharedPrefManager.getLocationEntityPref(),
                        mUserCurrentActivity);
                storeAndSendLocationInformation.storeAndSend();
            } else {
                // If the location information is not available
                mAppUtilInstance
                        .logDebugMessage(TAG,
                                "Location information is not generated to store and send.");
                mAppUtilInstance
                        .broadcastStatusMessage(
                                mContext,
                                Constants.STATUS_MSG_127
                                        + "Location information is not generated to store and send.",
                                Constants.STATUS_CODE_127);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: can you please show some code for your `onReceive` method ?

Comment: can you start multiple Alarms using different `requestCode` in your `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` method ?

Comment: Already I have implemented 2 different alarm with different request code. I will update my onreceive code along with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android API 11 you can call the [goAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()) in `onReceive()` method. This method returns an object of the [PendingResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult.html) type. The Android system considers the receiver as alive until you call the `PendingResult.finish()` on this object. With this option you can trigger asynchronous processing in a receiver. As soon as that thread has completed, its task calls `finish()` to indicate to the Android system that this component can be recycled.

Here is one [Sample Project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/CPU-Java/GoAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/tuning/goasync) to demonstrate `goAsync()` on `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I have tried. I have started a Handler with post delayed duration of 20 sec. But it never calling the handler at the specified time interval once the app quits. I tried goAsync() also . But still the   receiver is not alive I think.

Comment: please see the mentioned `goAsync` example code, that would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager with a PendingIntent works. This is how I do it in one of my apps:

```
    myAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myNewIntent = new Intent(MyCurrentActivityClass.this, MyNewActivityClass.class);
    Calendar wakeUpTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    wakeUpTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int) myTimeRemaining); 

    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyCurrentActivityClass.this, 0, myNewIntent, 0);
    myAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeUpTime.getTimeInMillis(), myPendingIntent);
```

You can also put the following in your MyNewActivityClass to wake the device and show through the security screen.

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    //make the activity show even the screen is locked.
    Window window = getWindow();

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

Comment: Why is this answer -1? It is working code from an app that does exactly what is described in the question.

Comment: I was inside of the alarm onReceive method. Inside of this metho I have to implement a timer. The code you have shared is to set the alarm. I already did this.

Comment: You had not posted the contents of your classes or any Java when my answer was given a -1 and my answer is a valid working solution to your problem. Even though it does not work exactly how you specify it would functionally do what you want. I tested my app and the activity starts even when I shutdown the app.